# Print data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func submitAnswer(_ sender: Any) {
    getData()
    print(array)
}

func getData() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("hobbies")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "cost").queryEqual(toValue: "low" )
    query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let hobbyName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "hobbyName").value as? String
        self.array.append(hobbyName!)
    })
    { error in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The idea here is that when I press the submit button, console will print out data from Firebase. After launching the app, when I press it, the console print an empty array. when I press it again, the console printed the result I wanted. I want to make it print the correct result on the 1st try. How do I do this ?

Comment: Hi, You want to print the output on the button second click?

Comment: No, on the first try.

Comment: Now u'r getting an empty array as result?

Comment: Launch the app, first time click -> empty, second time -> correct array. I want to get the correct result from 1st time

Comment: See my answer :) @TrầnHuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing your datasource, in your case, it's the `self.array` before your Firebase call completes. What you need to do is either:

1. Print your data inside the completion block, like so:

   ```
   @IBAction func submitAnswer(_ sender: Any) {
       getData()
   }

   func getData() {
       let ref = Database.database().reference().child("hobbies")
       let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "cost").queryEqual(toValue: "low" )
       query.observe(.childAdded, with: {( snapshot) in
           self.array.append((snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "hobbyName").value as? String)!)
           print(array) // Print inside this block instead :)
       }) { (error) in
           print(error)

       }
   }
   ```
2. Or if you really want to print your data inside your `submitAnswer` function, then you would need a completion block in your `getData()` function, like so.

   ```
   @IBAction func submitAnswer(_ sender: Any) {
           getData {
               // Completed! Now you can print your updated data from your datasource.
               print(array)
           }
       }

   func getData(withBlock completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
           let ref = Database.database().reference().child("hobbies")
           let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "cost").queryEqual(toValue: "low" )
           query.observe(.childAdded, with: {( snapshot) in
               self.array.append((snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "hobbyName").value as? String)!)
               completion()
           }) { (error) in
               print(error)

           }
       }
   ```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I just want to test if data is retrieved correctly since I am new to Firebase. Without the printing part, the data is still store in the array after the 1st click right ?

Comment: Even though "the printing part" is good now, it's kinda strange because I can't seem to use the data afterward for manipulation. Am I missing something here.

Comment: Hey @TrầnHuy, you can post a new question about it, and we'll be happy to help you out.